# Hosting a paid event with a member ticket and a non-member ticket

Tags: wordpress, civievent, civimember, registration

Consider the following situation. Martin is a member of our non-profit organization and would like to register for a seminar that we host. We offer either a member ticket of $150 and a non-member ticket of $250. Obviously, Martin opts for the member ticket. How does CiviCRM control whether Martin is indeed a member and is allowed to register for the $150 ticket?

Comment: Welcome. What research have you done on this and what specific problem have you faced with the documentation and demo? At Stack Exchange, the expectation is for you to do some research on the issue and then share it. The content of your post is a basic, out of the box functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [cividiscount](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount) extension and set up automatic discounts of $100 on the relevant events based on membership.  Non-members pay $250, those with the automatic membership discount pay $150.  Members need to log in before booking so that their membership status is known.

Comment: This is exactly how we've done this on multiple sites. People just have to make sure they're logged in. Hopefully you already have log-ins set up on your site for folks and you've got their membership statuses inside CiviCRM. :)

Comment: Thank you Aidan and Jenni. I am exploring the functionality of CiviCRM and see if it matches our needs. Unfortunately, I am not that tech savvy so the documentation is sometimes overwhelming. Next step is finding out where to set up log-ins so Aidan's proposed solution can be tested.

Comment: Logins are handled by the CMS (Drupal, WordPress, Joomla) - which one are you using?